# Display date from data base in JDateChooser

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdatechooser

I am working on a java project using SQL and I need to display the current date on a `JDateChooser`.

Before my client change it with his need I used this in the constuctor

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
jdatechooser.setDate(date);
```

I've also tried

```
   java.util.Date mydate = new java.util.Date();
   jdatechooser.setDate(date);
```

But neither of them work. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

JDateChooser from JCalendar 1.4 works fine.

I've just tested this example where `this` is a `JPanel`

```
   JLabel label = new JLabel("Choose date");        
   this.add(label);

   Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2011, Calendar.JULY, 3);
   calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);

   Date date = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

   JDateChooser jdc = new JDateChooser();
   jdc.setDate(date);

   this.add(jdc);
```

[image: Choose date]

`JDateChoose.setDate` accepts `java.util.Date`. You have to convert your obtained time from the DB to it.

BTW: You have a typo on your second excerpt, maybe that's the problem

```
java.util.Date mydate = new java.util.Date();
jdatechooser.setDate(date);
```

Should be

```
java.util.Date mydate = new java.util.Date();
jdatechooser.setDate(mydate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Date Get_Date = new Date(); // this code to get the current date

jDateChooser1.setDate(Get_Date); // to set the current date to jDateChooser

Comment: Please post the answer if you have an alternative or value ad to the existing answer. Right now, this solution is covered in existing answer.